# R package to make a linear discriminant analysis scatter plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, discriminant-analysis

Is there a package in `R` that can do this plot on LDA data 
graph plot: [image]

original question: [How does linear discriminant analysis reduce the dimensions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22884/how-does-linear-discriminant-analysis-reduce-the-dimensions)

Comment: As the one who plotted that (albeit not in `r`) I may say: if there is even no ready program, it can be written. The plot is actually a scatterplot (with spikes to group centroids) with 5 groups: 3 classes + 2 discriminant scores clouds which are straight chains when drawn in the space defined by original variables V1, V2. So, the only trick necessary to plot them is to compute coordinates of the discr. scores (which you get from LDA) onto V1, V2. The coordinate is the `score * corresponding eigenvector element`; eigenvectors of the LDA.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232251/how-can-i-plot-a-biplot-for-lda-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a package `adegenet`. For example:

```
library(adegenet)
data(dapcIllus)
x <- dapcIllus$a
grp <- find.clusters(x, max.n.clust = 40)
dapc1 <- dapc(x, grp$grp)
scatter(dapc1)
```

[image]

For more information read [this](http://adegenet.r-forge.r-project.org/files/tutorial-dapc.pdf).