# Why is the Scaling Matrix in LDA unnormalized?

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis, eigenvalues, svd

I was carrying out LDA (linear Discriminant Analysis) and noticed that the Scaling matrix produced by R is not normalized. Here is an example:

```
(res <- MASS::lda(Species~., iris))
Call:
lda(Species ~ ., data = iris)

Prior probabilities of groups:
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
 0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333 

Group means:
           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
setosa            5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
virginica         6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
                    LD1         LD2
Sepal.Length  0.8293776  0.02410215
Sepal.Width   1.5344731  2.16452123
Petal.Length -2.2012117 -0.93192121
Petal.Width  -2.8104603  2.83918785

Proportion of trace:
   LD1    LD2 
0.9912 0.0088
```

Normalizing the scaling matrix:

```
scale(res$scaling, F, sqrt(colSums(res$scaling^2)))
                    LD1          LD2
Sepal.Length  0.2087418  0.006531964
Sepal.Width   0.3862037  0.586610553
Petal.Length -0.5540117 -0.252561540
Petal.Width  -0.7073504  0.769453092
attr(,"scaled:scale")
     LD1      LD2 
3.973222 3.689878
```

Why is the scaling matrix not normalized?

Notice that if we try to fit lda manually:

```
x <- scale(as.matrix(iris[,-5]), TRUE, FALSE)
y <- iris[,5]
means <- tapply(x,list(rep(y,ncol(x)), col(x)), mean)
Swithin <- crossprod(x - means[y,])
Sbetween <- crossprod(means)
eig <- eigen(solve(Swithin, Sbetween))
eig[[2]][,eig[[1]] > 1e-8]
         [,1]         [,2]
[1,]  0.2087418 -0.006531964
[2,]  0.3862037 -0.586610553
[3,] -0.5540117  0.252561540
[4,] -0.7073504 -0.769453092
```

Notice that the results Obtained by directly computing the scaling matrix is normalized. Of course the difference between the manually computed scaling matrix and the one produced by lda is the scale factor.

**But this has an impact on the posterior probabilities.**

Looking at the R code, i noticed they are doing `svd` twice rather than doing `eigen` decomposition.
Tried analyzing the R code and after hours came up with the following:

```
a <- svd((x - means[y, ])/sqrt(nrow(x) - nrow(means)))
S1 <-  a$v %*% diag(1/a$d)
S1 %*% svd(means %*% S1)$v

           [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  0.8293776  0.02410215 -3.176869
[2,]  1.5344731  2.16452123  1.965956
[3,] -2.2012117 -0.93192121  2.076870
[4,] -2.8104603  2.83918785 -1.447218
```

Question: This is exactly like the unnormalized Scaling. But what is the intuition behind it?

**Main QUESTION**: in LDA Why is the scaling matrix not normalized? and How can I obtain this unnormalized scaling matrix using eigen decomposition? (Note that I am more interested with eigen decomposition since the eigenvectors are the solutions to the lda problem - But i do not mind having the SVD approach)

The `lda` objective:
$$\max_{w} J(w) = \max_{w} \frac{w'S_{between}w}{w'S_{within}w}$$

### EDIT:

I have found out that the formula used in R is the same used in python. Am I  missing something regarding `lda`?
Python too does give the unnormalized vectors.

if interested in the python code check [`here`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9aaed4987/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py#L513)

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48859/3277

Comment: LDA of iris data https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/82497/3277 There in my answer you will see three matrices also observed in your question: eigenvector matrix, it normalized, and discr. coefficient matrix based on the 1st.

Comment: @ttnphns thanks for the link.  Reading through the link, i could not find the reason as to why we use the unnormalized scaling matrix, the logic behind their computation. (Ie i can easily find them using lda function) but that is not my goal. It seems that other than the simple notion of optimizing the $J(w)$ function, there is more to LDA that i am missing. I do not know how to logically compute the unnormalized scaling matrix snd why it should be unnormalized. (Note that i gave the R code above on how to obtain this but i dont understand its logic. ) python uses similar code.

Answer (score 3):

Please study both my links in the comments. The [1st](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48859/3277) gives the LDA extraction algorithm formulas, and the [2nd](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83114/3277) (in my answer there) contains the demonstration of LDA on iris dataset according to such computations. I am not using R's term "scaling matrix", finding it a bit vague.

Per the [algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48859/3277) expressed in my 1st link, LDA produces **eigenvalues** (which we recalculate into canonical correlations) and **eigenvectors**$^1$. Eigenvectors - we can multiply them by the *constant* $\sqrt{N-k}$ to obtain the (raw, unstandardized) **discriminant coefficients** $\bf C$ (called by you "unnormalized scaling matrix") which are the coefficients to compute **discriminant scores** with. Alternatively, we could *normalize* the eigenvectors to column SS=1, to obtain the matrix $\bf C_n$ (you call it "normalized scaling matrix") [usable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22889/3277), for visual purposes, as the (oblique) **rotation** matrix of the variables into the discriminants.

So, you may use either way to get the values (scores) of the discriminants ($\bf X$ being the centered analyzed variables): one via discriminat coefficients: $\bf XC$, another via normalized eigenvectors: $\bf XC_n$. The first set of scores have the property that their pooled within-class covariance matrix is the identity matrix. The second set of scores are the perpendicular projections of the data points onto the discriminants as axes drawn in the space of the variables. By both sets of scores, the discriminants are uncorrelated variates. But, as drawn in the space of the original variables, they are not orthogonal axes.

By tradition, the first way to compute discr. scores is used most often by packages.

[As far as I'm aware, R and Python do not follow the fast algorithm I described under my link. They probably use equivalent, slower yet computationally more stable, variant utilizing SVD instead of eigendecomposition. Again, I'm mentioning that issue in my linked answer.]

---

$^1$ Because $\bf{S_w^{-1} S_b}$ of LDA isn't symmetric, its eigenvectors does not have to be an orthonormal matrix, unlike eigenvectors of PCA.