# Linear Discriminant Function

Tags: multivariate-analysis, discriminant-analysis

In linear discriminant analysis, how is the linear discriminant function determined? Assuming equal variance-covariance matrices, is the linear discriminant function determined from the training data?

Comment: The formula given by @Mimshot is only for 2-class situation. See complete set of formulas to get the discriminants for k-class situation [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48859/3277)

Answer (score 1):

For [Linear discriminant analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) the linear discriminant function is just the inner product of a given data point $\vec{x}$ with the vector $\vec{w}$, with the criterion $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{w} > c$. The vector $\vec{w}$ is calculated as:

$$\vec{w} = \Sigma^{-1}(\vec{\mu_0} - \vec{\mu_1})$$

Where $\vec{\mu_n}$ is the vector mean of sample class $n$, that is, the mean of the training data for class $n$.

Comment: So you could not compute a linear discriminant function given just one point?

Comment: @DonutPhil If you have just one point, what is there to discriminate?