# Robust quadratic form loss

Tags: machine-learning, robust, loss-functions, quadratic-form, robust-standard-error

I am using a loss function in quadratic form:
$$
l(w) = w^TAw \\
s.t. w^TBw=1
$$
where both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive definite. $A$ and $B$ are between-class scatter matrix and within-class scatter matrix, respectively. An explanation of between-class/within-class scatter matrix can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123490/what-is-the-correct-formula-for-between-class-scatter-matrix-in-lda).
I want to estimate $w$ by minimizing $l(w)$. 
If there are outliers in my dataset, they could have great (or even adversarial) impact on my estimation of $w$, through $l(w)$. I am wondering if there is any techniques to robustify $l(w)$. For example, we use Huber loss instead of square error loss to reduce the impact of outliers. Any paper/tutorial/comments are appreciated!

Comment: $w=0$ minimizes that function for all data, but this probably isn't what you're after. Can you explain more about what problem you're trying to solve and what $w$ is?

Comment: @Sycorax Sorry I forgot to put down a constraint. I have added it now. Thanks

Comment: Thank you--adding constraints helps.  Could you also indicate how your dataset might be connected to the quantities $w$, $A$, and/or $B$?

Comment: @whuber the data is connected to the loss by between-class scatter matrix $A$ and within-class scatter matrix $B$, as in Fisher discriminant analysis. Thanks!