# Importance of linear discriminants to classification at a given point

Tags: bayesian, classification, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

Many outstanding answers here detail the fundamentals of linear discriminant analysis. These include descriptions of [its use in dimensionality reduction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/algebra-of-lda-fisher-discrimination-power-of-a-variable-and-linear-discriminan/48859#48859), an explanation of [classification using Bayes' rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31366/linear-discriminant-analysis-and-bayes-rule-classification), and   a description of [within- and between-class scatter matrices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123490/what-is-the-correct-formula-for-between-class-scatter-matrix-in-lda).

Common methods for measuring importance of discriminants to classification as a whole (eigenvalue and correlation-based) are included in the [first answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/algebra-of-lda-fisher-discrimination-power-of-a-variable-and-linear-discriminan/48859#48859). These seem to tackle the problem, "How important is discriminant *d* for separating clusters in general?" I am searching for something slightly different:

**How important is discriminant *d*, *given the value of an input point, x, that we would like to classify***?

What I've tried so far: iteratively removing discriminants and calculating class probabilities at *x* using Bayes' rule. Stopping when statistical difference between iteration *i* and *i+1* exceeds a threshold. I would prefer, however, a non-iterative solution that is more similar to the direct calculation of discriminant coefficients.