# Comparison of LDA vs KNN time complexity

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis, k-nearest-neighbour, time-complexity

Which algorithm has a better performance in terms of time complexity, LDA or KNN?

Comment: This seems like it should be perfectly answerable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Time complexity depends on the number of data and features.

LDA time complexity is $O\left(Nd^{2}\right)$ if $N>d$, otherwise it's $O\left(d^{3}\right)$ ([see this question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/142565/60613)). It's mostly contained in the training phase, as you have to find the within class variance.

k-NN time complexity is $O\left(Nd\right)$. Actually, training without preprocessing is instantaneous ([check this book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/time-complexity-and-optimality-of-knn-1.html)), testing takes most time as you have to compare each test instance to most (or even the whole) training data.

Said that, without any other optmizations, k-NN should run incrementally faster than LDA as you add more dimensions to your problem.

Also, k-NN time complexity is pretty much insensitive to the number of classes in most implementations. LDA on the other hand has a direct dependence on that.