# LDA scores too big

Tags: matlab, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis, multi-class, centering

I'm trying to do dimensionality reduction with linear discriminant analysis (LDA) in MATLAB. I'm using [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29673-lda--linear-discriminant-analysis) to calculate the coefficients.

But I'm confused whether (and when) should I center the data. So I have 3000-dimensional features and 4000 samples, with class labels from 1 to 5. The features are histogram bins, so they are nicely normalized, i.e. each member is between 0 and 1.

```
% data is 4000x3000
NTrain = size(data,1);

% center the data : (should I ?) 
data_centered = bsxfun(@minus, data, mean(data,1)); 

% calculate the coefficients and scores :
W=LDA(data_centered,labels); % I also tried W=LDA(data,labels);
newData = [ones(NTrain,1) data_centered] * W';
```

in the end, I get a `W` (and `newData`) matrix with very big values, in the order of `1e4`. So I'm probably doing something wrong. Should I center the data beforehand?

Also what about new (test) data? I am saving `W`, but should I also save the training mean, so I can subtract it from test data to obtain the scores?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I cannot help specifically with the Matlab function. But [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48859/3277) is the algebra of LDA, with a link to the example of computations for iris data. Data in LDA always get centered because in LDA we deal with scatter or covariance matrices.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks. I further analyzed the external code, and it seems like it calculates the covariances directly (without centering it) , so it looks like I need to center it beforehand. But I'm still confused because the class coefficients are in very different orders.

Comment: Covariances _imply_ [centering](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) the data even if they use the "fast" formula which looks as if bypassing it. So, when computing scores, have the data centered.

Comment: Why do you add `ones` to your `data` before projecting it with `W`? Aren't `W` vectors supposed to be 3000-dimensional, not 3001-dimensional?

Comment: @amoeba I'm not sure about that as well, but the external code I'm using (link in the question) has an example projection as a comment, it projects like that. I think the first coefficients correspond to constants. **Edit:** now I think about it, if there are constant terms, maybe I'm **not** supposed to center the data before projecting?