# What is "Discriminant hotelling"?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, terminology, discriminant-analysis, hotelling-t2

Recently I have encountered the term **Discriminant hotelling**. And I have no idea what this term means. All I know is that this is in context with *multivariable data analysis*. I tried googling but in vain. So can someone explain to me what this term means?

Comment: Hotelling is the name of a statistician and goes with capital latter. Discriminant must be referring to "discriminant function analysis" and goes with lower-case. But what does `Discriminant hotelling` mean - I don't know, sorry. Do you mean hotelling as derivative from "hotel": short-term provision of office space to a temporary worker?, and speaking really of abuses of discriminatory hoteling?

Comment: No no, it has nothing to do with hotels.. :). .its totally a statistical term..

Comment: OK then. Linear discriminant function analysis (LDA) [is based on](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48786/3277) eigendecomposition of $\bf{W^{-1}B}$ where W and B are the within and the between scatter matrices. The sum of the eigenvalues = trace of the above matrix is known as Hotelling's trace. It is the multivariate analogue of "B/W" idea of ANOVA.

Comment: There is no such an exact term "Discriminant hotelling", at least I've never heard of. Where did you encounter it? Maybe they meant something like "Hotelling's discriminant" which fuses with my previous comment well?

Comment: I saw this on a presentation. Is there any chance that this could be a multivariate testing method of something (like normality or something else)?

Comment: Hotelling's T test is a multivariate test analoguos to univariate Student's t-test and based on the above eigenvalues.

Comment: -1 because there is no such term, as explained by @ttnphns above. So this question is un-answerable.

Comment: The phrase *does* appear in Google searches with a slash, as in [Discriminant/Hotelling](https://www.google.com/search?q="Discriminant+hotelling")--and in a few instances even without the slash.  A pattern emerges upon examining these instances: they tend to be in obscure badly-formatted journals (meaning editing was poor or nonexistent), written in English by non-English speakers.  A reasonable hypothesis is that "Hotelling's Discriminant" test was intended.

Comment: @whuber You are right. These are two different terms. I came across a software for data analysis where  `Discriminant/Hotelling` was given as an option.

Comment: Without a precise reference the value of this question is limited.

Answer (score 8):

**Discriminant hotelling** or discriminant/hotelling is somewhat ambiguous (@amoeba) and seems to be ***poor word choice*** (@whuber). An example of that usage appears [here](http://www.isca.in/AVFS/Archive/v3/i1/ISCA-RJAVFS-2014-018.pdf). The context in that paper is the [Hotelling's T-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling's_T-squared_distribution), together with [Discriminant function analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_function_analysis).

Hotelling's t-squared [statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling's_T-squared_distribution#Statistic) is a generalization of Student's t statistic that is used in multivariate hypothesis testing. The overlap with discriminant analysis is hinted at in the presentation of [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance), which  is closely related to Hotelling's T-square distribution used for multivariate statistical testing and Fisher's Linear Discriminant Analysis that is used for supervised classification.

Discriminant analysis and Hotelling's T$^2$: [Beware](https://folk.uio.no/ohammer/past/multivar.html): The combination of discriminant analysis and Hotelling's T$^2$ test is sometimes misused. One should not be surprised to find a statistically significant difference between two samples which have been chosen with the objective of maximizing distance in the first place! The division into two groups should ideally be based on independent evidence. Indeed, in the cited paper above, the classification was properly taken *a priori*.

Comment: @amoeba Even if that is the answer to the OP question, that answer could  be problematic, as above.