# How are the coefficients of linear discriminants calculated in lda()?

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I am trying to understand how the coefficients of linear discriminants are calculated in `lda()`.
Consider the following data set.

```r
library(MASS)
S<-matrix(c(2,.5,.5,1),2,2)
set.seed(1)
X<-data.frame(rbind(mvrnorm(25,c(0,0),S),mvrnorm(25,c(3,2),S)),Class=c(rep("First",25),rep("Second",25)))
lda.fit<-lda(Class~X1+X2,data=X)
```

`lda.fit` contains the following data.

```r
Call:
lda(Class ~ X1 + X2, data = X)

Prior probabilities of groups:
 First Second 
   0.5    0.5 

Group means:
               X1         X2
First  -0.2205177 -0.1224064
Second  2.7965638  1.8489960

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
         LD1
X1 0.3476010
X2 0.7330707
```

It seems that the vector of coefficients should be calculated using the formula
$$
\bf w\propto{\bf S}_W^{-1}({\bf m}_2-{\bf m}_1),
$$
where ${\bf S}_W^{-1}$ is the inverse of the pooled covariance matrix, ${\bf m}_2$ and ${\bf m}_1$ are the sample means of the groups (the formula comes from page 189 of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher M. Bishop).

```r
Sh<-((25-1)*cov(X[1:25,1:2])+(25-1)*cov(X[26:50,1:2]))/(50-2)
w<-solve(Sh)%*%(lda.fit$means[2,]-lda.fit$means[1,])
```

`w` is equal to

```r
        [,1]
X1 0.8668882
X2 1.8282180
```

and this does not coincide with the results in `lda.fit`. However, both of these vectors (`w` and `coef(lda.fit)`) have the same direction. `w` is a scaled version of `coef(lda.fit)` and vice versa.

Could someone explain how the coefficients of linear discriminants are calculated? How is the scaling factor chosen for `coef(lda.fit)`?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you search the site? There is at least about a ten of answers explaining how discriminant coefficients are computed.

Comment: @ttnphns That is exactly what I did. I was not able to find an answer that explains how exaclty `lda()` calculates the coefficients of linear discriminants. I guess there might different ways, but I would like to know how `lda()` does that. If you could post a link to answer that explains this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Sorry, lazy to search all the good answers, but here is one, my own, showing how discriminants are extracted in the general case of >=2 classes. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48786/3277