# Does cross-validation work for this type of modelling time-series

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

I am new to working with time series. I have come across the statement that k-fold cross-validation is not be suitable for time-series, but I have a doubt that this restriction does not apply to my situation.

My time-series are restricted to a certain interval, let's say 12 months.
Furthermore assume that I have 100 samples of time series, respectively 100 sequences of values, for which I assume that they were generated by the same process. The individual samples (one sample = one series = one sequence) are incomplete, for example one sample could have missing measurements in month 1 and 6, and another sample misses measurements in months 2 and 4. I want to learn/create a model which allows me to predict the missing values of samples I haven't seen before.

Naively, I would assume that I can do 5-fold cross-validation here by splitting my 100 samples into five folds of 20 samples each, train on four folds and validate on the fifth, repeating for all possible validation folds.

I don't see how this could lead to data-leakage, since I do not split any one series into several parts. Rather, I treat each series as an individual sample.

Am I correct in my assumption that I am doing something else than the usual 'forecasting' here, because I assume a restricted time-horizon, into which my inference falls as well? What is the name of this problem? I assume one could still say that I am forecasting in some sense, because in inference I might be confronted with a series which misses data for all but the first month.

Or am I missing something fundamental here and cross-validation is indeed inappropriate?

Comment: https://hub.packtpub.com/cross-validation-strategies-for-time-series-forecasting-tutorial/

Comment: Possible dups: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195414/cross-validation-techniques-for-time-series-data,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76376/how-is-hyndmans-explanation-of-proper-time-series-cross-validation-different-fr