# Does it make sense to use the correlation matrix from PCA in LDA?

Tags: pca, discriminant-analysis

I'm coming from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106121/does-it-make-sense-to-combine-pca-and-lda) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54547). I kind of understand what it does running PCA before LDA. However I don't really understand what I have to perform LDA. In the correlation matrix? Here I have all variables centered and scaled and ready to be "weighted" predictors

Which would be the steps to follow?